# Understanding percentage based divs and responsive design

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have set html and body width and height to 100%.  Why isn't this enough to allow my background images to display (#home1, #home2, #home3)? doesn't this set the pixels that all divs will base their height off of?  I want the content to dictate the height on the footer and header, ie no pixel height.  The layout should be: logo...full height (minus header and footer).  #photo-group...full height (minus header and footer). The class .pic-group should make each photo 30% of #photo-group. Currently, no image displays unless I make place a pixel height on class .pic-group. Is what I want to do possible and I have missed something obvious?  Setting a pixel based height will 'insult' my attempt at a fluid layout.

```
<?php 
session_start();
include('debug-code.php');
$thisPage = "home";
$title="";
$metaDesc="";
include('head.php');?>
<style>
html {
height:100%;
font-size: 100%;
overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
font-size:16px;
color:#434c50;
font-family: arial, serif;
background:white;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

.clearfix:after {
content: " "; /* Older browser do not support empty content */
visibility: hidden;
display: block;
clear: both;
height:0;
}

#home-container {
position:relative;
margin:0 auto;
width:70%;
background:white;
}

#home-content {
position:relative;
}

#home-content .content {
width:100%;
}

div.logo.home {
position:relative;
float:left;
width:60%;
background:#fdf2fd;
}

div.logo.home img {
width:60%;
}

#home-footer {
position:relative;
bottom:0;
background:#d5d0d5;/*url('../images/footerBG.png')*/;
color:white;
border-top:1px solid #05577a;
}

#home-footer .content {
margin:0 auto;
width:70%;
padding:1.5rem 0;
}

#photo-group {
display:block;
width:20%;
height:100%;
float:left;
}

.pic-group {
height:30%;
display:block;
position:relative;
}

#home1 {
background: blue url('../images/home1.png') no-repeat top left;
background-size:100%;
}

#home2 {
background:yellow url('../images/home2.png') no-repeat top left;
background-size:100%;
}

#home3 {
background:red url('../images/home3.png') no-repeat top left;
background-size:100%;
}
</style>
</head> 
<body> 
<?php include('home-header.php')?>
<div id="home-container"><div class="content clearfix">
        <div id="home-content"><div class="content clearfix">
            <div class="logo home"><?php include('logo-home-image.htm');?></div>
            <div id="photo-group">
            <div id="home1" class="pic-group"></div><div id="home2" class="pic-group"></div><div id="home3" class="pic-group"></div>
            </div>
            <?php include('home-menu.php');?>
            <div id='mobile-menu'></div>            
        </div></div><!--end content-->  
    <?php include("disclaimer.htm") ?>
</div></div><!--end container-->
<?php include("home-footer.htm") ?>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly set `height` on a div to make it fill out the available height of its `offsetparent`. In this case the body. Div elements are block elements. This means that by default they take up the available width of their offsetparent. By the height is by default set to auto. Which means that it increases when the content inside the div is wrapped into a new line.

However you expect that your divs take up all the space from the body. But the body isn't the offsetparent for the #home divs.

Offsetparents:

```
#home > #photo-group > #home-content > #home-container > body
```

But on `#home-container` you haven't set a height and set the position to relative. So this becomes the `base` for all child divs. The set their height *relatively* to this div. So setting `30%` on `0` results in `0`. Explicitly setting `300px` works of course. This let's the content of the #home overflow its parent.

Comment: Your response helped me in a number of ways. I have included the image I need in the html instead of as a background image. Am I correct to infer from your answer that background image cannot be used unless the height is set explicitly 'somewhere' in the chain of divs? If so, how would one maintain a fluid layout (%) for responsive design? Java?

Comment: @Leslie Setting a background does not trigger height. Compare it to real life. If you put a poster into a small photo list it will only show a part of the poster because the dimensions don't match. Fluid designs aren't a problem with css. You only need to set the correct offsetparent with a height. If you give `#home-container` height `100%` it should give you results.